# how do i get datas from bracket in iOS swift?

Tags: php, ios, swift

How do I get/extract datas from bracket/object in iOS swift???

I used `println(datas)` to display in Xcode6 console log:

`Optional({"status":"fail","message":"Invalid Username or Password"})`

note:
server code: php language.

I want to get this datas from that object or array. I don't know what that is.
I want to specifically display status in a specific label. 
I want swift code if possible. Thank you very much!!! :D hehe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You PhP code returns a JSON, its like this:

```
{  
   "status":"fail",
   "message":"Invalid Username or Password"
}
```

Its an NSDictionary type data, So receive it in an NSDictionary, lets call it responseData.

Then If you want to get `status` then write this:

```
let status = responseData ["status"]! as String
```

For `message` :

```
let message = responseData ["message"]! as String
```

**From your provided code:**

```
var task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
    var jsonResult: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSDictionary
    let status = jsonResult ["status"]! as String
    println(status)
    let message = jsonResult ["message"]! as String
    println(message)

})
```

Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: im still new to ios, can u walk me through, what is NSDictionary? how do i declare it? like for example var responseData = NSDictionary?

Comment: @KenDanTinio > How are you getting the data? Can you share that code?

Comment: how about 
`{
"status":"success",
"user":
{
"first_name":"me",
"last_name":"Test",
"email":"yeah@gmail.com",
"address":"Sibonga",
"city":"Cebu",
"country":"CA","zip":"6000",
"ssnlast4":"0000",
"mobile":"09325897521",
"confirmed":true,
"reg_type":null,"status":1,
"user_type":"individual",
"dob_month":"8",
"dob_year":"1992",
"cover":null,
"has_card":true
}
}`

how do i get a json wihtin a json?

Comment: @KenDanTinio > Same as before, it would be better if you post a new question or, paste your JSON with a better view.

Comment: i cant ask questions anymore :(  can i have your email? plssssss

Comment: @kendantinio> will skype do? rashad.bitmascot is my skype address.

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
var jsonText = //your json text
var data : Dictionary<NSObject, NSObject> = 
NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(text.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)!, options: nil, error: nil)
```

Comment: where is the jsonText has been used?

Comment: what's your `datas` object above? I think it's a kind of json object or json text.